# Windows 11 doesn't approve my credentials for RDP or SMB

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, smb, arm, credentials

I hope you can help me with this problem as solutions that i have googled does not help me.

I have received a new ARM tablet (Xiaomi Book 12.4) with Windows 11 Pro on board. I don't remember the version it has been shipped with but updating it to 23H2 (22631.3296) did not resolve the issues. I even tried an online reinstall option and it did not help. Also, I am using a local (non-Microsoft) account.

Issue 1: there is this ARM tablet with Windows 11 Pro and a remote PC with Windows 10 Pro. I am trying to connect to the Win10 PC via RDP, it fails on the securing connection step and says that the login attempt failed. I tried connecting to another Win10 machine and the error is the same. Also, connecting from other machines, including a x64 Win11 PC and an Android phone works fine.

Issue 2: I can't access a Win10/Win11 network shares from this tablet, it just says that the credentials are wrong though they are definitely not. Other machines manage to access this share easily. The fun part is that the connection works perfectly in the opposite way - I can access the tablet's SMB share from the Win10 machine. Also, accessing the forementioned Win10 share from other devices, including an Android phone, works fine.

What should I do to fix this?

UPD:

RDP error:
[RDP error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Y6W.png)

SMB error:
[SMB error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVELW.png)

Comment: Please give the exact error messages that you get for the two issues, and especially error-codes. Screenshots are fine.

Comment: Added screenshots but they do not show any codes. BTW, I tried net use and it returns error 86.

Comment: Which of the computers is "Xiaomi-Book"?

Comment: Xiaomi-Book is that problematic tablet. I tried adding other computers' names and addresses with backslash before login, it didn't help. However, it seems to be not necessary when connecting from other machines.

Comment: If you're trying to connect *from* Xiaomi-Book, you should specify the target computer name as the target domain.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and the error is the same. Also, I never do it when connecting from any other computer with both Win10 and Win11 and it works. So, unfortunatelu, this is not the case.

Comment: I sometimes found that it works better without a domain-name. Try also to find more information about the error in the Event Viewer. Another try would be to temporarily disable the firewall on the target computer.

Comment: Tried disabling the firewall and, just as expected, it did not work. If there were any problem with it, it would affect other connecting computers and there would be a network error. Also, I don't see any suspicious messages in event viewer on both tablet and target PC.

Comment: Is the Windows 10 computer fully updated? Try to [Remove Cached Credentials](https://helpdesk.yourofficeanywhere.co.uk/kb/a238/remove-cached-credentials-from-microsoft-remote-desktop-client.aspx) and retry using computer-name and also IP address.

Comment: All computers are updated. The issue persists even when I'm trying to connect to a x64 Win11 machine. The problem is definitely somewhere in the tablet's OS. Also, it doesn't have any cached credentials as I have just fully reset the system to see if it helps.

Comment: You confirm that the problem on concerns RDP from Windows 10 to 11, with no problem from 11 to 10. There are many posts about this, but no solutions I could find, so we need to hunt some more. (1) Run `gpedit.msc` and check on both computers that that no policy is configured in *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Security*. (2) Are you using local logins on all computers? (3) In W11 check *Settings > System > Remote Desktop > Remote Desktop users* (4) Are user accounts all administrators?

Comment: Could it have to do with Cyrillic characters? Was the machine set up originally with a different alphabet? Though new keyboard layouts can be added, it might be that there is a conflict with the *original* language.

Comment: for the logon window in your screenshots, you should use the exact same value for the computer and user domain, like: `192.168.1.101\Владислав`. Is that username correct? I've seen `а́в` instead of `ав` for example. Just to be sure, try typing the username/password from a valid device into notepad, copy the file to the tablet, and copy+paste into the login form. A bad tablet keyboard layout may use the wrong visually-identical `a` vs `а` character or try to auto-correct others.

Comment: So, I guess the OS was just faulty. I managed to reinstall it from scratch and now all network features work fine without entering machine names and with Cyrillic. I experienced some problems with drivers, e.g. screen turning didn't work, but I repaired it somehow. Also, I tried to reinstall original recovery image from Xiaomi, and it also had forementioned network issues. Dealing with WoA is a bit insane.